# Laravel Homestead Blank Screen With Text "EOF"

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

[image: Blank Screen EOF]

I just installing vagrant, virtualBox, and Homestead,
I set my homestead.yaml and when I run vagrant up it only shows blank white screen with text EOF in there

Do you guys have any clue why this happen?

here's my homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 1024
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\Code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: siapp.homestead
      to: /home/vagrant/code/JN1/SiAPP-web/public
      php: "7.2"

databases:
    - homestead
    - siapp_master
    - siapp_jn1
    - jatim_cerdas

backup: true

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

#services:
#    - enabled:
#        - "postgresql@12-main"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

ports:
    - send: 33060 # MySQL/MariaDB
      to: 3306
#    - send: 4040
#      to: 4040
#    - send: 54320 # PostgreSQL
#      to: 5432
#    - send: 8025 # Mailhog
#      to: 8025
#    - send: 9600
#      to: 9600
#    - send: 27017
#      to: 27017
```

enter code here

Comment: Can you add your `Homestead.yaml` to the question please?

Comment: yeah i edited the question, you can see my homestead.yaml there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by tried to reinstall vagrant, virtualbox, and homestead and restart the computer.